# PHP UTC String to date

Tags: php, date, timezone

I have a problem. In my code I have the following line:

```
$RunDateTimeGMT0 = "2017-12-31 23:00:00";
```

The goal is to get the previous and next hour, so I tried this:

```
$RunDateTimeGMT0 = "2017-12-31 23:00:00";
$epochRunDateTimeGMT0 = strtotime($RunDateTimeGMT0);
$previousEpochDateTimeGMT0 = $epochRunDateTimeGMT0 - 3600;
$nextEpochDateTimeGMT0 = $epochRunDateTimeGMT0 + 3600;
```

But then the I get the following result:

```
previousEpochDateTimeGMT0 -> 2017-12-31 21:00:00
nextEpochDateTimeGMT0 -> 2017-12-31 23:00:00
```

Because of my timezone `(+1)` the `RunDateTimeGMT0` gets converted to a date of my timezone.
I want the following result:

```
validEpochDateTimeGMT0 -> 2017-12-31 22:00:00
nextEpochDateTimeGMT0 -> 2018-01-01 00:00:00
```

How can I keep the date object UTC?

Comment: use [date_default_timezone_set('UTC')](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php)

Comment: You're not showing how you go from a timestamp to a readable date. And the `)`, after the 3600, must cause an error message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `Carbon` library. after import this library you should parse the date with this :

```
$RunDateTimeGMT0 = "2017-12-31 23:00:00";
$epochRunDateTimeGMT0 = Carbon::parse($RunDateTimeGMT0);
```

in [this link](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/), you could see the documentation of Carbon. Although, maybe you should to use this method :

```
$previousEpochDateTimeGMT0 = $epochRunDateTimeGMT0->addminutes(60);
$nextEpochDateTimeGMT0 = $epochRunDateTimeGMT0->subminutes(60);
```

I hope your problem solve with these lines, If another issue occurred you can ask.

Answer (score 1):

@Ebrahim Bashirpour already shared a way of doing this by using the Carbon library but you can also do this by just using the PHP Datetime class. It supports both [add time](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php) and [subtracts time](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.sub.php) in seconds. Take a look at the DateTime [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) for more details.

```
<?php
    $RunDateTimeGMT0 = "2017-12-31 23:00:00";

    $date = new \DateTime($RunDateTimeGMT0);
    $date->add(new \DateInterval('PT3600S')); //add 3600s / 1 hour
    $next_epoc = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); // 2018-01-01 00:00:00


    $date = new \DateTime($RunDateTimeGMT0);
    $date->sub(new \DateInterval('PT3600S'));//add 3600s / 1 hour
    $previous_epoc = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); //2017-12-31 22:00:00

    var_dump($next_epoc);
    var_dump($previous_epoc);
?>
```

Comment: yeah, we could use raw PHP Datetime class. But I prefer Cabon for more options.